# Why would a famous historical figure need to lie about their identity?

Tags: society, humans, identity

In my world, there are these [incredibly powerful and ancient weapons](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LegendaryWeapon) referred to as Divine Tools, which binds the wielder's soul to the spirit of a previous wielder trapped in them. The Divine Tools contain the souls of [historical and supposedly mythical figures](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeethovenWasAnAlienSpy) such as Tomyris, Leonidas, Scáthach and Albrecht von Wallenstein.

One such historical figure (heavily implied to be Jeanne d'Arc), has decided (for reasons unknown) not to reveal her identity to the person she has become soulbound to and use her [sister's name](https://www.jeanne-darc.info/biography/family/) as a pseudonym. Why would this be the case?

Comment: Are the tool-users aware of the general nature of these spirits? (Do they know they're specific dead humans? Do they know that they're usually famous?) And what's the nature of the relationship between tool and user? You mention that they're "bound", which implies to me that one seeks the other out specifically.

Comment: @Cadence The wielder's soul is transferred into the Divine Tool upon death, so as long as the wielder and spirit are bound together.

Comment: I apologize, but I believe this question is off-topic as too story-based because you are asking us to contribute a major (probably the major) plot point.  WB.SE's purpose is to help authors develop consistent rules for fictional worlds for which many stories can be developed.  The moment you ask about something that's only valuable to one story, it's a story-based question.

Comment: you should watch Fate Zero, it has a story line close to this; that could give you good ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Names have power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name)

If the wielder knew the spirit's true name, they would have greater control over the spirit and the Divine Tool. The spirit might not like that. The spirit might be opposed to whatever the wielder intends to do with the tool. Jeanne d'Arc, as a 15th century religious zealot, might have rather different ideas of what is moral than the wielder.